# Using spark sql DataFrameWriter to create external Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

As part of a data integration process I am working on, I have a need to persist a Spark SQL DataFrame as an external Hive table.

My constraints at the moment:

- Currently limited to Spark 1.6 (v1.6.0)
- Need to persist the data in a specific location, retaining the data even if the table definition is dropped (hence *external* table)

I have found what appears to be a satisfactory solution to write the dataframe, `df`, as follows:

```
df.write.saveAsTable('schema.table_name',
    format='parquet',
    mode='overwrite',
    path='/path/to/external/table/files/')
```

Doing a `describe extended schema.table_name` against the resulting table confirms that it is indeed external. I can also confirm that the data is retained (as desired) even if the table itself is dropped.

My main concern is that I can't really find a documented example of this anywhere, nor can I find much mention of it in the official docs -
 particularly the use of a `path` to enforce the creation of an external table. 
(https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter).

Is there a better/safer/more standard way to persist the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I rather creating the Hive tables myself (e.g. CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS) exactly as I need and then in Spark just do: df.write.saveAsTable('schema.table_name', mode='overwrite').

This way you have control about the table creation and don't depend on the HiveContext doing what you need. In the past there where issues with the Hive tables created this way and the behavior can change in the future since that API is generic and cannot guarantee the underlying implementation by HiveContext.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gonzalo. To be clear, are you recommending that I use a Hive create statement to specifically create the table in the desired location and then to leave the schema creation to the `saveAsTable` command? Or that I include as much of the table definition as possible in the Hive statement?

Comment: I do the full table definition always in the CREATE and I would expect (but haven't tried it) the save parameters to be ignored if the table already exist